# $modal.open is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show a progress dialog as a model by using ui.bootstrap, so I included it as a dependency in my application as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngCookies','home','ui.bootstrap']);
```

After injecting it my controller is as follows:

```
angular.module('home', [])
.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', '$rootScope', 'showAlertSrvc', '$modal',
function ($scope, $http, $filter, $route, $routeParams, $location, $rootScope, showAlertSrvc, $modal) {

    $scope.open = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'App/Register',
            controller: 'registerCtrl',
            //size: size,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });

        //modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        //    $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        //}, function () {
        //    //$log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        //});
    };
}]);
```

And my HTML is :

```
<input type="submit" value="Show Model" class=" novalidate form-control" ng-click="open()" style="background-color:skyblue; height: 45px" />
```

My View is named as Register.cshtml residing in App directory. Also routing is active at this URL. But when I click the button nothing happens, I wonder if templateUrl expects URL in any other format here. Please suggest what am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the path to the template with extersions

```
templateUrl: 'App/Register.cshtml',
```

Other options for `.open` look fine.

Comment: Still no advantage! Is "resolve" attribute is necessary for $model.open?

Comment: `resolve` needed for pass data from modal to your code. If you no need retrieve any data to main controller - down it.

Comment: Any errors in console on click the button? Or on load page?

Comment: nope ! On clicking the button, debugger hits the controller's $model.open function returns no error. But model is not opening!